# data.table efficiently finding common pairs between 2 columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, igraph

say I have a dataframe

```
  subject stim1 stim2 feedback
1      1003    50    51        1
2      1003    48    50        1
3      1003    49    51        1
4      1003    47    49        1
5      1003    47    46        1
6      1003    46    48        1
10     1003    50    48        1
428    1003    48    51        0
433    1003    46    50        0
434    1003    50    49        0
435    1003    54    59        0
```

I want to create a new column "transitive_pair" by

1. group by subject (column 1),
2. For every row in which feedback==0 (starting index 428, otherwise transitive_pair=NaN).
3. I want to return a boolean which tells me  whether there is any chain of pairings (but only those in which feedback==1) that would transitively link stim1 and stim2 values.

Working out a few examples.

```
row 428- stim1=48 and stim2=51
48 and 51 are not paired but 51 was paired with 50 (e.g.row 1 ) and 50 was paired with 48 (row 10) so transitive_pair[428]=True
    
row 433- stim 1=46 and stim2=50
46 and 48 were paired (row 6) and 48 was paired with 50 (row 2) so transitive_pair[433]=True
            
in row 435, stim1=54, stim2=59
        
there is no chain of pairs that could link them (59 is not paired with anything while feedback==1) so transitive_pair[435]=False
```

desired output

```
   subject stim1 stim2 feedback transitive_pair
1      1003    50    51        1             NaN
2      1003    48    50        1             NaN
3      1003    49    51        1             NaN
4      1003    47    49        1             NaN
5      1003    47    46        1             NaN
6      1003    46    48        1             NaN
10     1003    50    48        1             NaN
428    1003    48    51        0               1
433    1003    46    50        0               1
434    1003    50    49        0               1
435    1003    54    59        0               0
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!!

and putting a recreateble df here

```
structure(list(subject = c(1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 
1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L), stim1 = c(50L, 48L, 
49L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 50L, 48L, 46L, 50L, 54L), stim2 = c(51L, 
50L, 51L, 49L, 46L, 48L, 48L, 51L, 50L, 49L, 59L), feedback = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), transitive_pair = c(NaN, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 1, 1, 0)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 428L, 433L, 434L, 435L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns `"stim1"` and `"stim2"` define an undirected graph. Create the graph for `feedback == 1`, get its connected components and for each row of the data.frame, check if the values of `"stim1"` and `"stim2"` belong to the same component. In the end assign `NaN` to the rows where `feedback` is 1.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(igraph))

inx <- df1$feedback == 1
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df1[inx, c("stim1", "stim2")], directed = FALSE)
plot(g)
```

[image]

```r
g_comp <- components(g)$membership

df1$transitive_pair_2 <- apply(df1[c("stim1", "stim2")], 1, \(x) {
  i <- names(g_comp) == x[1]
  j <- names(g_comp) == x[2]
  if(any(i) & any(j))
    g_comp[i] == g_comp[j]
  else 0L
})

df1$transitive_pair_2[inx] <- NaN
df1
#>     subject stim1 stim2 feedback transitive_pair transitive_pair_2
#> 1      1003    50    51        1             NaN               NaN
#> 2      1003    48    50        1             NaN               NaN
#> 3      1003    49    51        1             NaN               NaN
#> 4      1003    47    49        1             NaN               NaN
#> 5      1003    47    46        1             NaN               NaN
#> 6      1003    46    48        1             NaN               NaN
#> 10     1003    50    48        1             NaN               NaN
#> 428    1003    48    51        0               1                 1
#> 433    1003    46    50        0               1                 1
#> 434    1003    50    49        0               1                 1
#> 435    1003    54    59        0               0                 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: the visualization is amazing- thank you! the second part gives me a series of errors 
e.g. Error: unexpected input in "df1$transitive_pair_2 <- apply(df1[c("stim1", "stim2")], 1, \" , Error: object 'x' not found, Error: object 'i' not found

any ideas what that could be?

Comment: @user15791858 I am using the new lambda `\(x)` introduced in R 4.2.0, if your version of R is older use `function(x)` and see if the error goes away. Run `R.version.string`, if it's prior to 4.20 then it's time to update R for free.

Comment: final question- your code doesn't group by subject (in case different subjects have different pairings, does it?

Comment: @user15791858 No, it does not. To group by subject I would rewrite the code as a function and apply it to each group of `subject`.